# How to create instance of generic class passing a method reference in constructor with kotlin

Tags: android, generics, reflection, kotlin

Now that I'm using kotlin as my main programing language I'm trying to simplify Android's Recyclerview implementation logic and I'm stuck at following point:

Let's say I have defined the following ViewHolder class, where a click position event is propagated via a method reference in the constructor.

```
class CustomViewHolder(itemView: View, val onClick: (Int) -> Unit)) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        onClick.invoke(adapterPosition)
    } 
}
```

How could I build an instance of a generic class that has a method reference in the constructor?

My recyclerview implementation has a generic class in the constructor and also an entity reference to be able to create an instance of my CustomViewHolder class by reflection at onCreateViewHolder:

```
class CustomAdapter<HolderClassGeneric>(val entityClass: Class<HolderClassGeneric>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderClassGeneric>() {

    /*
    Usual recyclerview stuff
    */ 

    //Method that I want to be called when a list item is clicked
    fun onListItemClicked(position: Int) {
       //do stuff
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HolderClassGeneric {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(listItemLayoutResourceId, parent, false)

        val constructor: Constructor<HolderClassGeneric>
        val instance: HolderClassGeneric
                                                            //I'M STUCK HERE
        constructor = entityClass.getConstructor(View::class.java, ?¿?¿?¿?¿)
        instance = constructor.newInstance(view, this::onListItemClicked)

        return instance

}
```

If what I want to achieve is not possible, would it be possible to pass the method reference using a setter by reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Kotlin lambda is usually translated as a FunctionX object, being X the number of parameters it has, so if you're looking for the representation of a lambda function like `(Int) -> Unit` it would be `Function1<Int, Unit>` so you could simply do:

```
entityClass.getConstructor(View::class.java, Function1::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter function like a *factory*.

```
class CustomAdapter<HolderClassGeneric>(val entityFactory: (View,  (Int) -> Unit) -> HolderClassGeneric) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderClassGeneric>() {

    /*
    Usual recyclerview stuff
    */ 

    //Method that I want to be called when a list item is clicked
    fun onListItemClicked(position: Int) {
       //do stuff
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HolderClassGeneric {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(listItemLayoutResourceId, parent, false)

        val instance = entityFactory(view, this::onListItemClicked)

        return instance

}
```

Comment: sorry, this is not what I'm looking for